# How to pass through pages using selenium and c#

Tags: c#, web-services, selenium, boolean

This is most likely a error of logic in my code.
In first place, what i'm trying to do is:

- go to the respective page of my website which is in this case [link](https://www.codigo-postal.pt/?cp4=4710&cp3=) and collect the data, with my public void GDataPicker.
- now where i want you to help me is, i use the following code to see if the button next exists in the webpage, and collect it's respective data, but always give me the same error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>     (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)' , i think it's probably because i don´t update my NextButtonElement.

Code:

```
Boolean ElementDisplayed;
try
{
    Gdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.codigo-postal.pt/");
    IWebElement searchInput1 = Gdriver.FindElement(By.Id("cp4"));
    searchInput1.SendKeys("4710");//4730
    IWebElement searchInput2 = Gdriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cp3"));
    searchInput2.SendKeys("");//324
    searchInput2.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    IWebElement NextButtonElement = Gdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[13]/a"));
    GDataPicker();

    while (ElementDisplayed =  NextButtonElement.Displayed)
    {
        GDataPicker();
        Gdriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2000));
        NextButtonElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    }
}
catch (NoSuchElementException i)
{
    ElementDisplayed = false;
    GDataPicker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you with C#, however StaleElementReferenceException occurs when the element you act upon is still in the dom but has been replaced with an identical one. what i would do is catch that exception and find the element again

```
catch (StaleElementReferenceException i)
    {

        IWebElement NextButtonElement = Gdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[13]/a"));

    }
```

http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I would use ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable with the dynamic wait feature selenium has.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(GDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement NextButtonElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[13]/a")));
```

ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable does exactly what you want it to do, wait a little bit until the element is displayed and not stale.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you
    /// can click it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="locator">The locator used to find the element.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IWebElement"/> once it is located and clickable (visible and enabled).</returns>
    public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementToBeClickable(By locator)
    {
        return (driver) =>
        {
            var element = ElementIfVisible(driver.FindElement(locator));
            try
            {
                if (element != null && element.Enabled)
                {
                    return element;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

From https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs